# How do I make a String array increment?

Tags: java, string, loops

I am getting jumbled up with this and I might know the answer. How do I make my `String[]` array increment every time this function is called?
Here is the function code:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){

        //The /ticket command
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ticket")){
            //Gets amount of arguments
            int size_of_args = args.length;

            String ticket = null;
            String[] ticket_array;

            //Puts ticket into one string to be stored.
            for (int i=0; i<=size_of_args; i++){
                ticket = ticket + args[i];
            }


            return true;

            } else {return false;}
    }
```

I think I have to do a for loop, but I am very tired and this has been stumping me for quite a while. The function is not complete, so do not mention that I haven't used `String commandLabel` or `CommandSender sender` (sorry if that sounds rude). Thanks in advance!

P.S. I do not want to set a value for `String[] ticket_array` because the amount of tickets made should be as many as there are sent in.

Comment: What do you mean by "incrementing" the array?

Comment: @jacobm Sorry about my clarity. I mean increment the value at which `ticket` is stored. So the first time the function/method is called `ticket_array[0] = ticket;` and second time `ticket_array[1] = ticket;`and etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a List instance as class member, this way, you don't need to worry regarding the size, for example:

```
List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<String>(50);

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
    //The ticket command
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ticket")){
        String ticket = "";
        // ommiting
        commandList.add(ticket);
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to this concept, what does this do and how do I access it in the future(like you access a string with `ticket_array[10];`)?

Comment: Well, go here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Comment: I cannot read that very well. I am rather new to Java. I am illiterate :D

Comment: Then that's your chance to learn :-P. seriously - how can I help with that?

Comment: @VinylScratch if you can't walk the walk - don't talk the talk. +1 to Binyamin.

Comment: @VinylScratch: the ability to learn from the Java tutorials is a learned skill, and similar to most all learned skills, it gets better with practice. Keep at it, and your "reading" abilities are guaranteed to improve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly but it sounds to me like you want to access a higher index of the array every time the function is called. If that's the case then you may want to consider using a static counter variable. this would have to be defined outside the scope of the function but it could be incremented during the function call

```
static int arrayCounter = 0;

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel,            String[] args){
    //The ticket command     
    arrayCounter++;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

then use

```
ticket_array[arrayCounter];
```

to access the desired index